# Как проинициализировать FlutterActivty в дефолтном проекте Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Создаю в Android Studio проект Flutter, проект запускается. Но когда перехожу в нативную часть. Не инициализируется FlutterActivity. Что не так с проектом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете попробовать следующее: ПКМ на модуль android во вкладке Project, Flutter->Open Android module in Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо открыть не как `flutter` проект, а как `android` проект. Т.е. по пути `*project*/android/build.gradle` и выполнить `Gradle Sync`. Если выйдет окошко с `Android Gradle Plugin Update` выбрать `Don’t remind me again for this project.`